# Adding a selector to UISwitch in Swift 3 gives 'Use of unresolved identifier' error

Tags: swift3

I have a custom view in an actionsheet with a UISwitch and I want to capture when the switch is switched. The switch shows up fine, but when I use addTarget to call the function, I get - Use of unresolved identifier 'deferSwitchToggled'

```
let deferredFilterToggle: UISwitch = {
    let deferredFilterToggle = UISwitch()
    deferredFilterToggle.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    deferredFilterToggle.addTarget(self, action: #selector(deferSwitchToggled(_:)), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)
    return deferredFilterToggle
}()
```

Function below.

```
func deferSwitchToggled(mySwitch: UISwitch) {
    if mySwitch.isOn {
        showDeferred = true
    } else {
        showDeferred = false
    }
}
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 8):

For the given selector you are specifying, your `deferSwitchToggled` method needs to provide an unnamed argument:

```
func deferSwitchToggled(_ mySwitch: UISwitch) {
```

instead of:

```
func deferSwitchToggled(mySwitch: UISwitch) {
```

Comment: Don't forget to add `@objc` above your function, it's necessary otherwise it occurs a compiling error.